# Integrating R and Hadoop (using JRI)

Tags: java, r, hadoop, mapreduce, rjava

I have seen some option to integra R and hadoop like : RHadoop, RHipe , Hadoop Sreaming , RHive.

I dont have any experinece in R but i do have good exp in Hadoop. Approach i am talking about might be un-feasible or something else....

But can anyone share their opinions on this approach -

Can we integrate R and Hadoop using JRI : Since R function can be called from a java code (using JRI) .?
can we do something like : writing a hadoop mapreduce program in Java and if we need some functionality which is present in R , then call that R-Function in Java Mapreduce program?

Comment: I believe this might be the only way to use R + hadoop free from cost,  the other option using revolution analytic costs money.

Answer (score 2):

The steps to follow to get this working are:

- Install R with rJava on each of the data nodes.
- In the setup function of the map/ reduce job, initialize R using

code:

```
private String[] Rargs = { "--vanilla" };

private Rengine re = null;
private REXP rn = null;
re = new Rengine(Rargs, false, null);
```

- Then make calls to R in the actual map or reduce code using

code:

```
rn = re.eval("result<-\"Hello world\"");
if( rn != null ){
            System.out.println("Result is :"+rn.toString());
        }
```

- Finally, to run use something like:

code:

```
hadoop jar HelloWorld.jar com.example.HelloWorld -files libjri.so,libR.so,libRblas.so  -libjars JRI.jar -Dmapred.child.env="R_HOME=/usr/lib64/R"
```

you can include more files like R files, data files etc in the -files arguments separated by comma and it ll get shipped to the distributed cache. 
Make sure to use `re.eval("sapply(\"file.R\",source)");` to access the functions in file.R from Java

Comment: what about performance? Will it be same as streaming or worse ...any idea?

Comment: @user1158351 It should be a little better than streaming because  these calls happen in the same process through JNI whereas streaming is a different process